# Core-Plot highlighting a single candlestick bar

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

I have a `CPTTradingRangePlot` with a `CPTTradingRangePlotStyleCandleStick` style.

I'm looking for a way to highlight a specific (or a few) candlesticks with a different fill color (or a glow, or something), but I can't find a way to access individual candlesticks in a similar way that a `CPTBarPlot` has with `-(CPTFill *)barFillForBarPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)barPlot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index;`

Am I missing something here?
Can I somehow maybe access a specific candlestick after the data load, and then change the fill color?

I was also thinking about adding an Annotation Layer, and maybe draw a circle around the specific candlestick(s), but I don't want to use an image, since it will get stretched and pixelated when I'll adjust it's size.
Is there any way to draw a vector-based shape as an annotation around the candlesticks?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a request for that feature on the [Core Plot issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list). In the meantime, you can achieve the same look by using more than one plot, one for each different style.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I've submitted an enhancement request. I'll look into using more than one plot, but do I need to use the same data set? (so the positioning will match?) or do I use a new plot of one bar and somehow position it myself over the other plot? thanks

Comment: You can use the same data except the datasource should return `nil` or `[NSNull null]` for each point that should be skipped and drawn by another plot.